# Issue on MapView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, mkmapview

I am developing `MapView` on my application.I displayed `my current location and also nearest people locations.`but here my problem i am getting the nearest people location `(latitude and longitude values`) through WebServices.And i displayed  all peoples locations on MapView but some times People numbers will increased at that situation i displayed whatever i am getting the peoples latitude and longitude values ,this latitude and longitude values are refreshing every 2 seconds and  by using this code,i display pins on MapView.

```
 for (int y = 0; y <[lat count]; y++)
    {
        NSLog(@"MapView ");

        marketAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
        annotationCoord.latitude = [[lat objectAtIndex:y]floatValue];
        annotationCoord.longitude =[[lon objectAtIndex:y]floatValue];
        marketAnnotation.coordinate = annotationCoord;
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:marketAnnotation];
        [marketLocations addObject:marketAnnotation];

        [mapView reloadInputViews];

    }
```

but i want display whenever people number will decreased,i need to display only that number of people on `MapView`

The below picture is i had three member people near by me

[image]

by the i displayed three peoples on MapView.But i need to display whenever people will decrease on MapView its automatically the pins are disappear on the MapView .like this pic

[image]

the above pic have only one pin,but i need to display automatically while the based on the people latitude and longitude values. how can i remove people who not near my location.Can you please suggest me how can i modified my code to automatically display on MapView either increase or decreasing.Thank you

Comment: You can remove annotations as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all annotations of old locations that are in map view before loading new locations.

```
for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations) 
    {
        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]]) 
        {
            [mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
        }
    }

//If empty locations then display current location

[marketLocations removeAllObjects];

if([lat count]==0)
{

            marketAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
            annotationCoord.latitude = currentLocationLatitude;
            annotationCoord.longitude =currentLocationLongitude;
            marketAnnotation.coordinate = annotationCoord;
            [self.mapView addAnnotation:marketAnnotation];
            [marketLocations addObject:marketAnnotation];
            [mapView reloadInputViews];

}
for (int y = 0; y <[lat count]; y++)
    {
        NSLog(@"MapView ");

        marketAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
        annotationCoord.latitude = [[lat objectAtIndex:y]floatValue];
        annotationCoord.longitude =[[lon objectAtIndex:y]floatValue];
        marketAnnotation.coordinate = annotationCoord;
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:marketAnnotation];
        [marketLocations addObject:marketAnnotation];

        [mapView reloadInputViews];

    }
```

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: its working but last pin should not remove on mapview @vidhyanand

Comment: You are adding new pins using locations. Then why you want last pin not to be removed..!

Comment: i am getting latitude and longitude values from server side ,when i get empty latitude and longitude values at that situation i have to display only my current location @Vidhyanand900

Comment: Check my updated answer..! I am adding annotation with current location if you get empty latitude and longitude..!

Comment: your current location is exists in lat array or not. Check my updated answer    
You need to remove all objects marketLocations array before adding new locations. It will work...Once check it..!